VBA work, but needs tweaking to Save New version to the next sequential version
Below is my code, which is functional. However it needs a slight modification. As a developer, I work in versions. I am currently on v158. Now using this code should save a copy as v159, however it does not, it was saved as v2 (I initially started as v001, as I wanted my files to remain sequentially). This code should always create the next number from what the file is.
Sub SaveNewVersion()
'PURPOSE: Save file, if already exists add a new version indicator to filename

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim SaveExt As String
Dim VersionExt As String
Dim Saved As Boolean
Dim x As Long

TestStr = ""
Saved = False
x = 2

'Version Indicator (change to liking)
  VersionExt = " v"

'Pull info about file
  On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    myfilename = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine Base File Name
  If InStr(1, myfilename, VersionExt) > 1 Then
    myArray = Split(myfilename, VersionExt)
    SaveName = myArray(0)
  Else
    SaveName = myfilename
  End If
    
'Test to see if file name already exists
  If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt) = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt
    Exit Sub
  End If
      
'Need a new version made
  Do While Saved = False
    If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) = False Then
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt
      Saved = True
    Else
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Loop

'New version saved
  MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & x & ")"

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NotSavedYet:
  MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"

End Sub

This must also be able to work with any Excel file extension.  Like my current file is v158.xlsm The code should look between "v" and the file extension, this time ".xlsm" and see 158, then add 1, and the result would be v159.xlsm with the same file name.

You can access the filename and then extract only the digits with this function

Save Workbook With New Version Index
Sub SaveNewVersion()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Save New Version"
    Const VERSION_LEFT As String = " v"
    Const VERSION_DIGITS As Long = 3
    ' A file with no version will be saved as "* v002" ('FIRST_VERSION + 1').
    Const FIRST_VERSION As Long = 1
    ' If the following is enabled, and you have opened "* v002",
    ' it will be saved as "* v003" or which number is available.
    ' Otherwise, it will be saved as "* v002 v002" or which number is available.
    ' Try both to decide which one works for you.
    Const NO_SUBVERSIONS As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If this code is in the same workbook, use 'ThisWorkbook' instead!
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path
    Dim OldFileName As String: OldFileName = wb.Name
    
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This file (""" & OldFileName _
            & """) has not been initially saved." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "New file version not saved!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    FolderPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim BeforeLastDot As Long: BeforeLastDot = InStrRev(OldFileName, ".") - 1
    Dim FileBaseName As String: FileBaseName = Left(OldFileName, BeforeLastDot)
    Dim FileExtension As String:
    FileExtension = Right(OldFileName, Len(OldFileName) - BeforeLastDot)
    
    Dim ComparePattern As String:
    ComparePattern = "*" & VERSION_LEFT & String(VERSION_DIGITS, "#")
    
    Dim OldVersion As Long:
    If FileBaseName Like ComparePattern And NO_SUBVERSIONS Then
        ' Remove version from base name.
        FileBaseName = Left(FileBaseName, _
            Len(FileBaseName) - Len(VERSION_LEFT) - VERSION_DIGITS)
        OldVersion = CLng(Right(FileBaseName, VERSION_DIGITS))
    Else
        OldVersion = FIRST_VERSION
    End If
    
    Dim NewVersion As Long: NewVersion = OldVersion + 1
    
    Dim VersionFormat As String:
    VersionFormat = String(VERSION_DIGITS - 1, "0") & "#"
    
    Dim NewFilePath As String:
    NewFilePath = FolderPath & FileBaseName & VERSION_LEFT _
        & Format(NewVersion, VersionFormat) & FileExtension
    
    Do While Len(Dir(NewFilePath)) > 0
        NewVersion = NewVersion + 1
        NewFilePath = FolderPath & FileBaseName & VERSION_LEFT _
            & Format(NewVersion, VersionFormat) & FileExtension
    Loop
    
    Dim MaxVersion As Long: MaxVersion = 10 ^ VERSION_DIGITS - 1
    
    If NewVersion > MaxVersion Then
        MsgBox "Maximum version number (" & MaxVersion & ") exceeded." _
            & vbLf & vbLf & "New file version not saved!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FileFormat As Long: FileFormat = wb.FileFormat
    
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=NewFilePath, FileFormat:=FileFormat
    
    MsgBox "New file version saved.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub

